# Connecting two different widgets together on qt with python through a button

Tags: python, qt, widget, qt4, pyqt

I was wondering how to connect two widgets together. I have two widgets i created on QtDesigner, one being a Login page, and another being a Main Menu. I want to connect them so that when the Login is successful, the user will be redirected to the Main Window, and the Login widget will close automatically. Does anyone know how to do this?

PS.  I have the code for the main menu and login in separate .py files

Comment: You should show some code, this way the answer(s) you get will be more specific to your case.

Comment: alright yeah, that is a good point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

In your QApp create first a dialogue containing the login widget and execute the dialogue. Depending on the result, either (if login failed) quit the application (or reprompt the user for login), or (if login succeeded) instantiate the main window and show it.

Or:
Instantiate and show the main window. Immediately show an application-modal dialogue with the login widget. Depending on the result, either resume operation or quit the application.

Here a snippet from some code, that prompts the user for login and checks it against a DB. The login dialogue is defined as DlgLogin in another file.

```
#many imports
from theFileContainingTheLoginDialogue import DlgLogin

class MainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super (MainWindow, self).__init__ ()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow ()
        self.ui.setupUi (self)
        dlg = DlgLogin (self)
        if (dlg.exec_ () == DlgLogin.Accepted):
            #check here whether you accept or reject the credentials
            self.database = Database (*dlg.values)
            if not self.database.check (): sys.exit (0)
        else:
            sys.exit (0)
        self.mode = None
```

The dialogue class is the following (having two line-edit-widgets for the credentials):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from dlgLoginUi import Ui_dlgLogin

class DlgLogin (QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super (DlgLogin, self).__init__ ()
        self.ui = Ui_dlgLogin ()
        self.ui.setupUi (self)

    @property
    def values (self):
        return [self.ui.edtUser.text (), self.ui.edtPassword.text () ]
```

The application itself reads:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.3

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from mainWindow import MainWindow

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication (sys.argv)
    m = MainWindow ()
    m.show ()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ () )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

Comment: I already have the login page that works perfectly, but that has its own .py file. I also have another file for the Main Window, which is another widget...
im sorry, but i did not quite understand what you posted above

Comment: In my example the login is also in another file as the main window. Import your login dialogue and instantiate and execute it in your main window.

Comment: @Thaz I have added an import statement to the first snippet.

Comment: oh allright, i understand, but im still a bit confused about importing it :S from theFileContainingTheLoginDialogue import DlgLogin <- so do you have to put the directory of the ui file? or .py file?

Comment: You need to import the login dialogue CLASS, not its UI.